# Tomcat 6 uses old, non-existing web.xml

Tags: tomcat6, web-applications

I have a weird issue with Tomcat 6 and OpenGrok webapp, Tomcat seems to use some old, nowadays non-existing web.xml. I'm trying to add some roles for access control to the web.xml, but Tomcat never takes the new web.xml into use.

I've tried deleting the exploded webapp directory and the .war file, restarted Apache and Tomcat, and even tried reloading the webapp via the manager (not successfully, curl command does not seem to do anything, maybe it has something to do with the SSL we are using) - all but manager reload trigger the webapp reload, but still for some unknown reason the old web.xml and the roles in it are used. Webapp also works okay with the old roles.

Anybody have any clue how to force Tomcat to use the new web.xml? Server is RHEL 6.3, Tomcat 6.0.24, Apache 2.2.15.

Comment: Have you tried deleting temp & work folder?.

Comment: @StackPlayer: Never though of that, good suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't help, there's nothing in `/var/cache/tomcat6/temp/` and some .java and .class files in `/var/cache/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/source/org/apache/jsp/` - all of which seem unrelated to my problem. I deleted them but the problem did not go away.